# How to change the legend title?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have ggplot2 installed on my R studio version 3.6.1 and none of the specified codes to change the legend title work. I tried with:

```
labs(fill='New Legend Title') 
guides(fill=guide_legend(title="New Legend Title")), 
scale_fill_discrete(name = "New Legend Title")
```

The graphic is generated correctly but the legend name is not changed. Might there be any additional package that I may have to download?

***edit***
added the code provided by the OP in their comment below

```
ggplot(data.frame,aes(x=options,y=price,colour = BRAND))+ 
geom_point()+ 
theme_bw()+ 
theme(panel.grid=element_blank(), panel.border = element_blank(), legend.title = element_text(family = 'Arial',face = 'bold', size = 11), legend.text = element_text(family = 'Arial', size = 10))+ 
scale_color_manual(values = c('red','green'))+ 
xlab('OPTIONS')+ labs(fill='BRAND')
```

Comment: Without seeing your full code, it's hard to say, but you may want to check first whether you actually mapped the `fill` aesthetic (rather than `colour`).

Comment: @Mauro it would be helpful to see step by step what you have tried and each respective output. Please consider revising your question with as much content and context.

Comment: @Z.Lin here is the full code of the graphic: 'ggplot(data.frame,aes(x=options,y=price,colour = BRAND))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank(), panel.border =   element_blank(), legend.title = element_text(family = 'Arial',face = 'bold', size = 11), legend.text = element_text(family = 'Arial', size = 10))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red','green'))+
  xlab('OPTIONS')+
  labs(fill='BRAND')'

Comment: As suspected, you didn't actually map anything to `fill` in `aes()`. Change `labs(fill = 'BRAND')` to `labs(color = 'BRAND')` should suffice. Voting to close.